# MySQL stored procedure retrieve value

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_vk_suspend//
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_vk_suspend2()
declare today = DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
declare accid = INT DEFAULT 11;
set today = now();
BEGIN    
    SELECT * FROM members where expirydate < today;    
END //
```

This is my stored procedure. I have to add one or more query depend with id from members table. How can I retrieve id from members table.

ex: I have to add this query in my sp

```
UPDATE members 
SET suspend = 1 
WHERE id = 'some id from mem: tables'
```

Comment: you need update all members with `expirydate < today`?

Comment: yeah i need to update all expire members.

Comment: why not to try in this manner `UPDATE members SET suspend=1 WHERE expirydate < today`

Comment: i have to insert another table with expire member id

Answer (score 0):

i see IMHO cursors it's what you need

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM members where expirydate < today;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
DECLARE a INT;

OPEN cur1;

my_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

    UPDATE members SET suspend=1 WHERE id = a;
    INSERT INTO another(member_id) values(a);

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
```